# question on operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am trying to understand a program, which includes the following definition for a function f

```
void f(String S, const String& r)
{

}
```

Here String in the argument stands for a class. I am confused on the difference between the definitions of these two arguments: "String S" and "const String& r". S should represent an object of class String, then how about r?

In more detail, the f is defined as

```
void f(String S, const String& r)
{
   int c1 = S[1];  // c1=s.operator[](1).operator char( )
   s[1] ='c';      // s.operator[](1).operator=('c')

   int c2 = r[1];  // c2 = r.operator[](1)
   r[1] = 'd';     // error: assignment to char, r.operator[](1) = 'd'      
 }
```

This code snippet is to show how the operator overload, but these comments does not help me much. For instance, why r[1]='d' is nor correct?  Thanks for helping understanding it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const String& r` is a constant reference to String r.  Within the function, you access `r` just like a String.  The difference is that it is actually a reference to the object passed to the function, while `S` will be a copy of the object passed to the function.  You can *almost* think of it as if you are accessing `r` through a de-referenced pointer (though there is more to it than that).

Another way to look at it: The caller will see changes to `r` (if it wasn't `const`), while he will not see changes to `S`.

The `const` simply means the function `f` cannot modify `r`.

See also: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#overview-refs

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be just an example, to show the difference between ways of passing parameters.

One real case where you might pass one parameter by value, is when you need a copy of the value anyway. Perhaps when concatenating the two strings.